# python glob or listdir to create then save files from one directory to another

Tags: python, directory, glob, listdir

I'm converting documents from pdf to text. The pdfs are currently in one folder and then saved to another after txt conversion. I have many of these documents and would prefer iterating over subfolders and saving to a subfolder with same name in txt folder but having trouble adding that layer.

I understand I can use glob to iterate over recursively and do this for file lists, etc. But unclear how I can save files from this to new folder. This isn't totally necessary but would be much more convenient and efficient.

Is there a good way to do this?

```
import os
import io
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def convert(fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)

    output = io.StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = open(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text 
    print(text)



def convertMultiple(pdfDir, txtDir):
    if pdfDir == "": pdfDir = os.getcwd() + "\\" #if no pdfDir passed in 
    for pdf in os.listdir(pdfDir): #iterate through pdfs in pdf directory
        fileExtension = pdf.split(".")[-1]
        if fileExtension == "pdf":
            pdfFilename = pdfDir + pdf 
            text = convert(pdfFilename)  
            textFilename = txtDir + pdf.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
            textFile = open(textFilename, "w")  
            textFile.write(text)  


pdfDir = r"C:/Users/Documents/pdf/"
txtDir = r"C:/Users/Documents/txt/"
convertMultiple(pdfDir, txtDir)
```

Comment: So if a pdf is found in a subdirectory (e.g. `C:/Users/Documents/pdf/Setec Astronomy/employees.pdf`), do you want the textfile to be saved to `C:/Users/Documents/txt/Setec Astronomy/employees.pdf` or `C:/Users/Documents/txt/employees.pdf`?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay the first one C:/Users/Documents/txt/Setec Astronomy/employees.txt - and the program takes care of the txt part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, `glob` works nicely here. It can even filter only `.pdf` files.

Uncomment the 3 lines after you've tested it.

```py
import os, glob

def convert_multiple(pdf_dir, txt_dir):
    if pdf_dir == "": pdf_dir = os.getcwd() # If no pdf_dir passed in 
    for filepath in glob.iglob(f"{pdf_dir}/**/*.pdf", recursive=True):
        text = convert(filepath)
        root, _ = os.path.splitext(filepath) # Remove extension
        txt_filepath = os.path.join(txt_dir, os.path.relpath(root, pdf_dir)) + ".txt"
        txt_filepath = os.path.normpath(txt_filepath) # Not really necessary
        print(txt_filepath)
#        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(txt_filepath), exist_ok=True)
#        with open(txt_filepath, "wt") as f:
#            f.write(text)


pdf_dir = r"C:/Users/Documents/pdf/"
txt_dir = r"C:/Users/Documents/txt/"
convert_multiple(pdf_dir, txt_dir)
```

To determine the filepath for the new `.txt` file, use functions from the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) module.

`os.path.relpath(filepath, pdf_dir)` returns the filepath of the file including any subdirectories relative to the `pdf_dir`.

Suppose `filepath` is:

`C:/Users/Documents/pdf/Setec Astronomy/employees.pdf`

and `pdf_dir` is

`C:/Users/Documents/pdf/`

It would return `Setec Astronomy/employees.pdf` which can then be passed into `os.path.join()` along with `txt_dir`, giving us the complete filepath with the extra subdirectories included.

You could do `txt_filepath = filepath.replace(filepath, pdf_dir)`, but you'd have to make sure all the corresponding slashes are in the same direction, and there are no extra/missing leading/trailing slashes.

Before opening the new `.txt` file, any and all subdirectories need to be created. `os.path.dirname()` is called to get the filepath of the file's directory, and `os.makedirs()` with its `exist_ok` argument set to `True`, to suppress the `FileExistsError` exception if the directory already exists.

A `with` statement is used when opening the `.txt` file to avoid explicitly calling `.close()`, especially in case of any exceptions.